# using ng-if in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to build an ionic2 application,the shedule application send notifications to users,i want to do something like  this but it didn't worked

```
<div *ngIf="beacon.uuid=='ebefd083-70a2-47c8-9837-e7b5634df557'">{{schedule("ok","okkk")}}</div>
```

Comment: what is this value?`ebefd083-70a2-47c8-9837-e7b5634df557`

Comment: can you add the schedule function ?

Comment: the if should be in your .ts file, avoid mixing view, and function calls, also you might want to share the complete code (.ts included) for us to test. you can use https://plnkr.co/ for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code to this :

```
<div *ngIf="beacon.uuid==='ebefd083-70a2-47c8-9837-e7b5634df557'">{{schedule("ok","okkk")}}</div>
```

Use === instead of == , in Angular 2.

Comment: You can try it in your code , with == , and its most preferable that use === instead of == in angular 2. Thanks.